# What event object should be used when using an autocomplete function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a form that autocompletes the client name based on the input from the user.

HTML:

```
<label for="client">Facility Name/Account Number: </label>
<input type="text" oninput="dropdownTip(this.value)" id="client" NAME="client" style="width:100%;">
<label for="iname">Interpreter Name:</label> 
<input type="text" style="width:100%; text-transform:capitalize;" id="interpreter" name="iname" value="<?echo $interpreter;?>"/><BR>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#interpreter').autocomplete({source:'otp_autocomplete.php', minLength:2});
});

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#client').autocomplete({source:'otp_client_autocomplete.php', minLength:2});
});
```

The same form also populates additional fields based on the value of the client field using the following php generated javascript:

PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dropdownTip(value){
        var preamble = 'No Special Instructions';

        <?//Load options from DB.
            while($row =  mysqli_fetch_array($statuses)){
                echo "if(value == '" . $row['client_id'] . " - " . str_replace("'","\'",$row['client_name']) . "') {
                    preamble = '" . $row['Special_Instruction'] . "';
                } ";
            }
        ?>

        console.log(value);

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = preamble;
    }
</script>
```

Everything is working great, except that I would like the function "dropdownTip" to trigger as soon as the autofill option is selected. Currently it only activates once another field is clicked on, and does not activate at all in Internet Explorer.

I have been trying different HTML DOM events listed here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events

But I can't seem to find the right one.  Is there one that will provide the functionality I am looking for, and work with IE?